# firebase signInWithEmailLink method not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I installed firebase to my react app using **npm install firebase** command and initialized firebase like this

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth"
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {.........};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// export
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```

and i want to signInWithEmailLink method like this

```
import { signInWithEmailLink } from "firebase/auth";

const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    setEmail(window.localStorage.getItem('emailForRegistration'));
    console.log(window.location.href);
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("emailForRegistration"));

}, []);

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

try {
    const result = await signInWithEmailLink(
        email,
        window.location.href
    );
    console.log("Result", result);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
};
```

and it give me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObZbE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `useEffect()` hook. Follow the instructions from the firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth).